# How to check if there is at least: two letters, one number and one special character?

Tags: java, regex

How to check if there is at least: two letters, one number and one special character in java? Here is my code but I dont know if I'm in the right direction.

```
public static boolean validarCodigo(String codigo){
    //return Pattern.compile("[abc]").matcher("ba").find();
    boolean ContainsAtLeastTwoLetters = Pattern.compile("[0-9]").matcher(codigo).find();
    boolean tieneAlmenosDosLetras = Pattern.compile("('/[a-zA-   Z]/')").matcher(codigo).find();
    boolean ContainsAtLeastOneSpecialChar; = Pattern.compile ("'/[^a-zA-Z\\d]/'").matcher(codigo).find();       

    return ContainsAtLeastOneDigit && ContainsAtLeastTwoLetters && ContainsAtLeastOneSpecialChar;
```

Comment: No, it has to be at least one digit, two letters and a special character, the 3 conditions have to be true so the code is correct. srry if i didnt express correctly

Comment: Ok what is it - now you've given three different stories on what you want. In the title it's one of each. In the code it's two letters, two numbers and one special char and now you're saying one digit two letters and one special character? Which is it?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow. To update/correct your question you can use [[edit]] option under the question. Currently your comment says something different than your title so it would be good to select which of these are true and put it in question.

Comment: im trying to check if it has At least: 1 letter, 1 digit and 1 special char

Comment: So now you've contradicted your first comment.  Is it one letter or two letters?  (Hint: one and two are different numbers!)

Comment: ye im so sorry im pretty tired, At least 2 letters, 1 digit and 1 special char, which is -

Comment: One micro optimization could be to check input length is at least 4 chars before applying regex check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex seems a bit off but you've done a good job. One main thing is that you're only checking for **one** number and letter. To solve this, try the following regexes:

```
boolean containsAtLeastTwoLetters = Pattern.compile("[0-9].*[0-9]").matcher(codigo).find();
boolean tieneAlmenosDosLetras = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z").matcher(codigo).find();
boolean containsAtLeastOneSpecialChar = Pattern.compile ("[^a-zA-Z\\d]").matcher(codigo).find();
```

I took the freedom to reformat the variables to java standard practice (likeThis instead of LikeThis).

Comment: your special check will succeed if there's a space (for example) somewhere

Comment: @Bohemian Generally spaces are considered to be special chars.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean validarCodigo(String codigo){

   Pattern letter = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-z]");  
   Pattern digit = Pattern.compile("[0-9]");  
   // add or remove whatever special characters are permissible in your case
   Pattern special = Pattern.compile ("[!@#$%&*()_+=|<>?{}\\[\\]~-]"); 

   Matcher hasLetter = letter.matcher(codigo);  
   Matcher hasDigit = digit.matcher(codigo);  
   Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(codigo);

   return hasLetter.find() && hasDigit.find() && hasSpecial.find();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use look aheads to do it in one line:

```
boolean hasAllThree = codigo.matches("^(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\\d])(?=(.*\\d){2})(?=(.*[a-zA-Z]){2}).*");
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it has to be:

- at least one digit,
- two letters
- and a special character`

So your entire String need to exactly match each of these regexes

- `^.*[0-9].*$`
- `^.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*$`
- `^.*[^a-zA-Z\\d].*$`

### Here is some fancy way :)

Using [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism `(?=...)` you can create one regex that will check if your string matches all of these conditions. It can look like:

```
^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\\d]).*$
```

Now to check if your string is exactly the same as described in this regex use `matches` method. BTW method will also add `^` at start and `$` at end to your regex so you don't have to write them.

Your testing code can look like this

```
codigo.matches("^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z\\d]).*$")
```

Comment: thank you but it has to be at least one digit, at least 2 letters,at least one special digit which is -

Comment: @Agustin `^.*[0-9].*$` will match string with at least one digit, `^.*[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*$` will match string with at least 2 letters, `^.*[^a-zA-Z\\d].*$` will match string with at least one special character. It seams to me that everything is OK.

Comment: Sorry, my bad i didnt misunderstood what you said at the beggining, if the special char has to be "-" can i just use ("[-]");

Comment: @Agustin yes, It is even better to put it as literal `-` without `[]` around (unless you want to include other characters, in that case preferred way would be `[other\\-Characters]` `\\-` will make `-` normal character, without \\ it would mean "range" like in `[a-z]`)

Comment: ohhh thanks!, this is soo interesting but soooo complicated, at least for now ofc, thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Agustin Unfortunately you can only pick one. In most cases people mark the one that they will be using. You can always un-mark it and mark better one in case you marked wrong one.